# System.loadLibrary() вызывает java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError при обращении к нативной функции

Tags: jni

Я пытаюсь подключить библиотеку, допустим, "libHTTP_x86.so"
В статике я делаю так:

```
String libName = "HTTP";
    try {
        //если уже лежит в библиотеке
        System.loadLibrary(libName);
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        //иначе первое обращение
        String libs = System.getProperty("java.library.path").split(":")[0];
        File jsscLib = new File(libs, System.mapLibraryName(libName));

        if (jsscLib.exists()) {
            //похоже, это лишняя проверка
            System.load(jsscLib.getAbsolutePath());
        } else {
            try {
                //копируем нашу в библиотеку из пакета в первую папку с библиотеками
                copyLib(jsscLib);
                //после копирования опять пытаемся загрузить
                System.loadLibrary(libName);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                System.err.println("Fail while loading jssc library!");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Путь точно верный. Сам load вызывается без ошибок. А уже дальше, при первом обращении к нативной функции, например, `String versionNative = getNativeLibraryVersion(); //checking native works` я получаю исключение:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no HTTP_x86 in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
```

Я озадачен. Что не так?
Если что, вот эта строчка `String libs = System.getProperty("java.library.path").split(":")[0]` получается равной "/home/prog1/idea-IC-162.2032.8/bin"

Пробовал загружать прямо и конкретно - `System.load("/home/username/libHTTP_x86.so");`. Результат тот же.

Comment: Проверьте архитектуры (ABI). Загружать x86 библиотеку для проекта, скомпилированного для `armeabi`- плохая затея.

Comment: У меня есть библиотеки для всех архитектур. Я это опустил. Проблема не в библиотеке. Она же из такого же кода, только когда в пакете .jar, подключаемом мавеном работает нормально, а в проекте, если распаковать, выдаёт ошибку.